# Lists.asmx and List Item Attachments

Tags: 2010, javascript, web-services, html5, asmx

How would the lists.asmx service be used to add an attachment to a list item with JavaScript File API?

I cannot find an example of anything other than copy.asmx for adding documents.

**Update:**
Here is the code I am using. I have tried the FQDN of the server and the short form as in the code. I'm not sure what is going on but the error is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <soap:Body>
            <soap:Fault>
                <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
                <faultstring>Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.</faultstring>
                <detail>
                    <errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.</errorstring>
                    <errorcode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">0x8102006d</errorcode>
                </detail>
            </soap:Fault>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Code sample:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <AddAttachment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <listName>MarketNeed</listName>
            <listItemID>1</listItemID>
            <fileName>test.txt</fileName>
            <attachment>dGVzdA==</attachment>
        </AddAttachment>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>


var soapPayload = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><AddAttachment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"><listName>MarketNeed</listName><listItemID>1</listItemID><fileName>test.txt</fileName><attachment>dGVzdA==</attachment></AddAttachment></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';


$.ajax({
    url: "http://dev/sites/plm/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapPayload,
    complete: function(){ console.log("Done"); },
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use the [AddAttachment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.addattachment%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method of the Lists.asmx web service I believe. SO you'd first create the list item and in the response from that, it should tell you the list item ID which you can then pass into the AddAttachemnt method.

**Edit from OP:**

Here is the code I developed using PirateEric's suggestion. I needed to use [SPServices](https://spservices.codeplex.com/), as I could not seem to get the service to accept my `POST`. If you look at their code I am sure the single method could be implemented so as to avoid the weight of the entire library.

```
<img src="attachment-icon.png" id="SECRET-000234-attachment" class=".attachment-target" />

$('.attachment-target').each(function(){
    this.ondragover = function () { return false; };
    this.ondragend = function () { return false; };
    this.ondrop = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var itemInfo = this.id.split("-");
        var listName = plm.lists.byConfidentiality(itemInfo[0]).getMarketneedList();
        //The above code is a custom object that returns
        //the list name based on the "confidentiality"
        //of the item. We use 4 different lists to easily
        //manage the permissions. All perms are at teh list
        //level only.
        var itemId = parseInt(itemInfo[1]);


      var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0],
          reader = new FileReader();
      //In prod this would be in a for loop, of course.
      reader.onload = function (event) {
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "AddAttachment",
            listName: listName,
            listItemID: itemId,
            fileName: file.name,
            attachment: event.target.result.split(",")[1],
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                                     //Do stuff
            }
          });
      };
          return false;


};
});
```

Comment: PirateEric, thanks for the suggestion. Any ideas of what the error above might be caused by?

Comment: That's one thing I've never really figured out yet, is streaming a file or attachment through the web services/JSOM to a document library or list attachment. I know it has to be a base 64 encoded byte array.

Comment: I think I am getting it. I just uploaded a text file successfully. I'll post code soon.

Comment: Great, favoriting this post for reference. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Add the soap action parameter and its value, it will resolve your error.